# Why the trigger click is not working in this jsfiddle?

Tags: jquery

On document ready i am calling a function which triggers a click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fechIndianMarketsdata();
    $("#indian").click(function() {
        alert('clcikd called');
    });
    $("#usmarket").click(function() {
    });
});
function fechIndianMarketsdata() {
    //$("#indian").click();
      $("#indian").trigger("click")
};
```

But would you please tell me why the trigger click is not working in this case ?
https://jsfiddle.net/de3ns6x2/

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/de3ns6x2/1/

Comment: You have to call function after bind.

Comment: I'm really wondering if you are not a shared account. You ask many questions each day which seem completly unrelated each other and usually this is so simple fix i doubt you are trying to understand your issue. So are *you* some devs from some web agency??? But i note you are a(some?) polite guy(s?), good point on that! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trigger the event before the handler is bound. Call the function at the end of the block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#indian").click(function() {
        alert('clcikd called');
    });
    $("#usmarket").click(function() {
        // do something here...?
    });
    fechIndianMarketsdata();
});
```